# Axios only sends sessioncookie with withCredentials:true on the original route, but not on other routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

I'm working on a react project with nodejs for the server, on the frontend I'm using axios to make server requests, meanwhile on the backend I'm using express/express-session, to create session cookies, so I can verify the user and redirect them to specific routes, and show specific information.

However, I'm only being able to get that information from the cookies on the /login page, which is my landing page, from there, once the user logs in, and creates a session, with a button I get info from that session to send the user to their assigned role page, and restrict them from seeing other roles pages.

Or at least that's the intent, since right now I can't seem to access to that stored cookie from anywhere else that is not the /login route, I can see the cookie being there on the inspect tool, but req.session.user will be undefined unless I do the request from /login, for example I have this specific request I did for testing that I'm running on 3 different routes useEffect's, /login, /app, and /register, and it will only return something on the /login

`Axios.get('http://' + urlCustom + ':' + portCustom + '/orders',{withCredentials:true}).then((response)=> { console.log(response); })`

I have tried {withCredentials:true} and also setting Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; when declaring variables and functions at the beginning.

I don't think that the session is being deleted and created each time I move between routes, since the cookies don't change, and still works every time I come back to /login whether I do it by URL or by navigation.

Next I'll try to show you my code.

This is on my Login.js

```
  const [urlCustom, setServUrlCustom] = useState('x.x.x.x');//this does have an ip but i just want to hide it
  const [portCustom, setServPortCustom] = useState('3001');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;



  useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get('http://' + urlCustom + ':' + portCustom + '/orders',      
    {withCredentials:true}).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response);
    })
  })
```

basically it's the same for app.js and other .js for other routes,

now for the index.js of my back:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const session = require("express-session");

app.use(session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
      expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: false,
    },
  })
);//for the cookie parameters I've been trying multiple stuff, samesite true/false, secure/true false, etc., I'm open to suggestions lol.

app.use(cors({
  origin:["http://192.168.1.9:3000"],
  methods:["GET", "POST"],
  credentials: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/orders", (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  console.log("hola")
  res.send("req.session");
})
```

the idea is to just send req.session.user instead of the whole session on res.send, but to see if I would get something just like that on the other routes I tried sending it all, and it does, but it's just the basic session object that looks like this:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 86400000,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: false
  }
}
```

which you can get as a response even without a session created, meanwhile the response on /login looks like this:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-19T13:20:28.033Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: false
  },
  user: { nameuser: 'Juanc', passuser: 'EQSS', area: 'HR' }
}
```

also this is the request where the session is created:

```
app.get("/api/loginCheck", (req, res) => {
  let user = req.query.nombreUser;
  let passw = req.query.passUser;
  let encryptedPass = encyptPass(passw); //this is a custom function to encrypt a password
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (err) {
    
    
      if (err) {
        console.log("the sqlconnect error is " + err);
      }
      var request = new sql.Request();

      request.query(
        "select * from testusers.dbo.userslogin where nameuser = '" + user + "' and passuser = '"+ encryptedPass + "'",
        function (err, records) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("login error is " + err);
          } else {
            
            if (records.rowsAffected[0] == 0) {
              res.send("User or Password are incorrect.");
            } else {
                req.session.user = records.recordset[0];
                res.send(req.session.user);
            }
          }
        }
      );
    });  
});
```

that request is called when the user tries to log in with the usual form (id/password/login button)

So, to summarize the big post..
Once the user logs in, the same /login page hides the login form and shows a label saying "welcome" + username (that I get from the cookie with a new request, that works because I'm still on /login). And a button to redirect them to their specific Area page, which in this case is HR, but now I send him to HR and I can't check who the user is because axios is not sending the cookie when I'm at /hr.

My question is why is this happening, and if it's possible to fix it, thanks for reading all the way through, if I'm missing more code or more context please let me know, I'm pretty new with stackoverflow and react/node in general!

I've tried doing the same request from different routes and only works on the route I've made the session, even if the session cookie stays no matter if I navigate to different routes. I've tried withCredrentials true, and different cookie parameter settings on the express-session, and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong, please help!